# Docker and Gitlab - how to modify the docker run

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm very new to contentious integration with Docker and Gitlab.

I have a situation where my script in `.gitlab-ci.yml` needs to encode files with ioncube, but that's now fully possible due to some security restrictions that Docker has placed. Therefore, I need to modify the `docker run` command that Gitlab runs when I start a job for my Gitlab project.

According to [this page](http://blog.ioncube.com/2017/09/22/ioncube-docker-support/)...

> In addition, a change to the Docker security options on the container will be required to allow for the licensing process to function by using the –security-opt seccomp:unconfined option to the docker run command.

I need to adding that extra parameter to the `docker run` call, but since Gitlab does that somewhere, I have no idea how to proceed.

Is there a way I can get Gitlab to include `–security-opt seccomp:unconfined` when I run a job?

EDIT: I host Gitlab on my own server.

Comment: Are you using your *own* gitlab server, or are you asking about a repository hosted on gitlab.com?

Comment: It's my own Gitlab server. @larsks

Comment: So to clarify, are you asking how you can modify your Gitlab Runner (which is separate from Gitlab itself) to inject additional parameters when it's executing a Docker image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The GitLab CI Process executes it's Pipeline stages/builds via a GitLab Runner. (https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/).

The GitLab Runner is registered to a GitLab instance or a specific GitLab Project. The configuration that you specify in the gitlab-ci.yml file is what gets executed by the Runner. In your case, you're specifying the GitLab Runner to execute a Docker container.

There is some advanced configuration that you can do with the GitLab Runners (https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html). The setting that you are looking for is in this section: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runners-docker-section.

On the server that is hosting your GitLab Runner (or in the Docker instance that is hosting your GitLab Runner) modify the config.toml file (probably at /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml). You should see a [runners.docker] section if you've registered this Runner to execute Docker containers. It is in this section that you want to add in:

```
security_opt: ["seccomp:unconfined"]
```

Comment: `security_opt = ["seccomp:unconfined"]` worked for me